# how can convert BDC database to sql

Tags: sql, database

BDC is a format of babylon dictionary.
when you install babylon , database installed in "C:\ProgramData\Babylon\Gloss"
but "ProgramData" is hidden.
Now how can convert BDC database to another database format(sql and ...)?
thank you;)

Comment: this is BDC format but post("How to convert babylon glossary to sql format?") closed!! I'm really sorry for people who closed post.

Comment: Is [pyglossary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyglossary) of any help?

Comment: did you ever manage to convert it?

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_(software). Converting that to "SQL" makes no sense. SQL is a query language like `SELECT * FROM TABLE`. How would you expect to convert a dictionary to that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the native (Babylon) files in notepad or a similar text editor? If the Babylon files open as simple text then you'll have some options converting it to SQL. If the Babylon files open with gibberish then you are probably out of luck.